# "vote limit reached..." - better message please

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, usability, voting-limits

```
Daily vote limit reached; come back in 19 hours.
```

Why should I be asked to 'come back' if my vote limit has been reached.. am I asked to 'go away'?

couldn't the message be `'Daily vote limit reached; Limit will be reset in 19 hours'` .... or am I being too sensitive?

Comment: If you imagine someone saying that to you with tongue firmly in cheek, maybe it won't seem so harsh....

Comment: Try again in 19 hours?

Comment: i don't see any real difference between "try again..." and "come back...";  i think both are friendlier than "limit will be reset..." which sounds very cold and computer-y.  ryan, i think you're being too sensitive here.  no offense.  if the community decides it should be changed, i'd prefer the "try again" wording over "limit will be reset".

Comment: of course, I've been interacting with computers more than people lately :).... I actually prefer 'Try again' myself (i was the one who upvoted S.Mark's comment first)

Comment: How about "Daily vote limit reached; new votes arrive in 19 hours"

Comment: or "Daily vote limit reached for the next 19 hours"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changed to

> Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 19 hours.

Comment: Vote early, vote often!

Comment: @Popular Demand is Al Capone? OMG it all makes sense now!!!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe we should request a filling bucket algorithm.  You get another vote every 48 minutes, with the maximum being 30 votes at any given time.  If you haven't been here for a day you have 30 votes you can use immediately, but then rather than waiting another 19 hours, you'll get another one in less than an hour.