# Change "out of votes" notification text?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“vote limit reached…” - better message please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52090/vote-limit-reached-better-message-please)

When you have depleted your daily vote quota you get a message saying

```
Daily vote limit reached; come back in 4 hours.
```

If taken literally, the phrasing suggests to the user that there's no point in being here since he/she has no votes left.

I suggest a re-phrasing of the text to something along the lines of:

```
Daily vote limit reached. You will be able to vote again in 4 hours.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea! In the interest of brevity I am changing it to

> Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 4 hours.